# How do I unlock Golden Guns in Gears of War 2?

Tags: gears-of-war-2

Noticed that while playing **Gears of War 2** on Xbox Live, some of the other players will be running around and shooting down the horde with golden lancers and hammerbursts.

Where are they getting these versions of weapons from?

Is it something that needs to be unlocked in the game, or can you just buy them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The golden Lancer rifle was a special perk given to those who bought the Limited Edition version of Gears of War 2.  It doesn't convey any special abilities.

Comment: Walking around with bling is its own special ability